# Render React Component to Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fancybox

i have a react component and want to render it into plain HTML to throw the template into a fancybox.

Unfortunatelly I have no Idea whatsoever how to do that except of rendering the component to a html sting and give that to fancybox.

The problem is that I do not have a DOM element before which can be used to render the component into.

Did anyone do that before?

When I call

ReactDOM.renderToString() it tells me the Target container is not a DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing something like?

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

console.log(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div>foo</div>));
```

I have a working example here:
http://www.webpackbin.com/4JVJDJA8W

It renders the string and then sets the result as innerText on the page.

Comment: Hi no its more like console.log(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<ReactComponent props/>));

Comment: That should work. See my running example I just posted.

Comment: okay but as I am using redux I now get the error message: 
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Pnap)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Pnap)".

How can I access the store from my react component

Comment: Hmmmm... it's sounds like you a trying to render out a sub component of your application structure.  If you are going to do that you will have to wrap it with the necessary `Provider` and configured `store` as from your original react application.

Comment: okay yeah that makes sense but how do i retrieve that store to pass it to the Provider?

Comment: Just call it like you did in the original application. :) i.e. `createStore(...)`